# The returned value of toString :-)

Tags: javascript, tostring

I know this is a strange question, but it has been on my mind for some time.
Why does toString returns `object` for the first part of the returned value.
Like this -> `[object ...]`.

odd question :/

```
let func = Object.prototype.toString;

alert( func.call(123) ); // [object Number]
alert( func.call(null) ); // [object Null]
alert( func.call(alert) ); // [object Function]
```

here's the code.

Comment: show us the code which creates this. Likely you are trying to stringify an object. If you want to serialize an object into a json string use JSON.stringify()

Comment: What standard says to do https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-tostring